# How to do form post API in react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-hooks, http-post

I would like to add data to my database through the API url, with a form. But it's not really working. I'm kind of struggling to make it work. When I click on 'add' I check the array but nothing new is being added. I think i'm doing something wrong in the body variable. But not sure. How can i get the values from the form into the url API?
Here is my code:

```
export function AlbumForm(props) {
   const [PostId, setPostId] = useState(0);
    const {register, handleSubmit, errors, control} = useForm({
    defaultValues: props.album
        ? props.album
        : {
            name: "",
            artist: "",
            imageUrl: "",
        },
    }); 

    const useCreateAlbum =((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: data,
            mode: 'cors'
        };
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setPostId(data.id));
    });
  

    return (
        <div className="AlbumForm">
            <h2>Album Form</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(useCreateAlbum)}>
                <input type="text" {...register("name")} placeholder="Name" name="name"/>
                <input type="text" {...register("artist")} placeholder="Artist" name="artist" />
                <input type="text" {...register("imageUrl")} placeholder="ImageUrl" name="imageUrl"/>
                <button type="submit">{props.submitbutton}</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

never mind I solved it. I just had to do this:

```
const useCreateAlbum =((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify(data),/////here is the change
            mode: 'cors'
        };
        fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL, requestOptions)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => setPostId(data.id));
    });
```